# Haxe for enterprise application development

Tags: haxe, enterprise

Is there anything available for Haxe which would be suitable for real-life enterprise application development? (i.e. A professional high level UI component framework.)

Just a note - I know we all love our tools of choice, but please try to keep it objective.. don't just recommend Haxe for something without thinking about whether it's really an effective tool for business requirements.

Comment: For extra points (not really), if there is nothing, why hasn't anyone tried tackling this yet?

Comment: Haxeui is a good candidate for that, has lots of features and the code is clean and easy to understand/modify.

Comment: I couldn't find anything remotely close to a complex datagrid component when I looked, did I miss something? The target market here is the "just show me lots of data and grids and tree structures and data collection fields and validate it all etc etc omgomgomg" kind of business nerd.

Comment: I don't think there's much to be honest.  Most Haxe users seem to be doing custom UI (eg Tivo, Massive Interactive), game design, or web apps.  There is a WX Widgets integration called Waxe for desktop apps.  I believe there is decent Android support using the Java target, but have never tried.  But even as a major Haxe believer, I'd say: an off the shelf native UI framework with the kind of components you're expecting isn't really available.

Comment: If you post a comment on the issues at https://github.com/ianharrigan/haxeui I'm sure you'll get an answer, best luck.

Comment: @JasonO'Neil That seems to be the honest truth. But now I'm wondering what it would take to change that... BTW - by "web apps" did you mean web *applications* (to me this is enterprise development) or did you mean web *sites* (most Internet-deployed stuff)? It's hard to define the divide between the two, but I group web applications in the same category as thick-client business stuff (data-driven, graphs, reporting features, long-term use by a single user, etc) i.e. thick-client productivity applications which happen to be deployed via a browser.

Answer (score 2):

On one hand, as Jason suggested in his comment, there is missing a haxe-based native UI framework.

On the other hand, we don't really need a haxe-based UI framework, but using the UI framework available to the target platform is enough. Unlike building a library, which is better to be target independent, building a "real-life enterprise application" only requires targeting a specific platform. Since UI is highly dependent on the target platform, it means that we should use a target-specific UI framework. For example, the best UI solutions to an web app are probably jQuery, ReactJS, AngularJS etc., which all can be used in Haxe ([jQueryExtern](https://github.com/andyli/jQueryExternForHaxe), [react.hx](https://github.com/fponticelli/react.hx), [angular.haxe](https://github.com/frabbit/angular.haxe)). For Flash/Java/C#, we can simply use any "native" libs by `-swf-lib path/to/lib.swc`, `-java-lib path/to/lib.jar`, and `-net-lib path/to/lib.dll`. For C++, however, although there is continuous improvement (watch [the wwx2014 talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k2rw7-uL6RU)), it is still somewhat hard to use native libs.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Are you saying that you could use something like Apache Flex if you target Flash?  I was under the impression that it wasn't nearly that simple or easy (would require a port of Apache Flex to Haxe). Also, I thought the point of Haxe was that you'd write the code once and be able to deploy it anywhere.

Comment: Good point.  If you are targeting "Enterprise" then you can usually just target just one platform that you know the enterprise is using.  If this was Android, or a Java framework, or web/JS, or desktop using WX Widgets, you would have a decent path forward.

Answer (score 0):

We are making games in haxe + OpenFL + StablexUI. Not sure if it suitable to post their urls, so that you could see the quality. But it helps if you need your custom ui not native (iOS, Android).